# UI Тесты через TFS

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, tfs

Имеются UI тесты (python+pytest+selenium+allure). Проект создавался в Pycharm + интеграция с git TFS (сейчас проект в хранилище TFS). 
Стоит задача через TFS запускать эти самые тесты и после генерить отчёты.
Во всех мануалах необходима развёртка Visual Studio.

1. Обязательна она нужна?? ведь у меня готовый проект, в котором установлены все пакеты и зависимости, по сути нам нужно клонировать репо и запустить тесты.
2. Стоит задача, основные константы хранить в TFS (Пароли, логины, hostname и т.д.). Как легче всего это реализовать?? Создать файл в проекте и на стадии билда прописывать в этот файл константы, а после его чистить?
3. Может есть толковый пошаговый мануал??

Answer (score 0):

1. Студия нужна, чтобы собрать проект и получить тестовые модули, которые потом запускаются через тест-агенты. Pycharm не использовал, поэтому специфику не подскажу. Если ваш проект поддерживает запуск из командной строки, то вполне можно без студии обойтись.
2. Можно попробовать использовать переменные сборки, которые можно скрыть. Эти переменные потом можно передавать необходимым компонентам: [Variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch).
3. Можно официальные источники пока полистать, есть лабы:

   - [UI test with Selenium](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops)
   - [UI testing considerations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest)
   - [Automating Selenium Tests in Azure Pipelines](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/selenium/)